# Python Loop to write Dataframes to Excel Files if both the Dataframe and Excel File have the same name

Tags: python, dataframe, export

I have a dictionary of dataframes that I want to export to individual excel files stored in a specific directory.

I would like to set up a python loop that will export the dataframe (as a new sheet) to the excel file with the same name as the dataframe, and iterate through each dataframe.

This is what I have so far:

```
    multi_sheet_file = pd.ExcelFile(r'filename.xlsx')

    # Gets the sheet names in the file
    excel_sheet_names = multi_sheet_file.sheet_names

    dict_of_sheets = {}
    for sheet in excel_sheet_names:
        dict_of_sheets[sheet] = pd.read_excel(multi_sheet_file, 
    sheet_name=sheet)
```

How do I set up a python loop that will export  the dataframe to an existing excel file with the same name?

Comment: So are you trying to write a new file per dataframe? or are you trying to write a single excel file with multiple sheets?

Comment: And what is wrong with what you have so far? In fact, what is your question?

Comment: I am trying to write each dataframe to an existing file. So each of my sheetnames will correspond to an existing excel file with the same sheetnames. I want to loop through the sheetnames(dataframes) and write them to the excel file with the same name. Hopefully that isn't too confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to loop through your dictionary, where the keys are the sheet names:

```py
for sheet, df in dict_of_sheets.items():
    df.to_excel('some_excel_file.xlsx', sheet_name=sheet)
```

I'm not sure if this needs to be an ordered operation or not, but in py3.6+ dictionaries are ordered based on the order of key insertion if that matters